# how to align left 2 very long expressions

Tags: equations, multline

I have been trying to align these 2 equations for a while but I fail to align q(z) with j(z). I tried with

```
\begin{multline}
        q(z) = \frac{(1-\Omega_m)(3zw_a + 3w_0(z+1)+z+1)(z+1)^{3(w_a + w_0)}+(z+1)\Omega_m e^{\frac{3z w_a}{z+1}}}{2(z+1)[(1-\Omega_m)(z+1)^{3(w_a +w_0)}+\Omega_m e^{\frac{3 z w_a}{z+1}}]} \\
        j(z) = \Big[(1-\Omega_m)(9 z^2 w_a^2 + 3(z+1)w_a(6 w_0 z + 3z +1) + (9w_0(w_0+1)+2) (z+1)^2)\times\\(z+1)^{3(w_a+w_0)}+2(z+1)^2 \Omega_m \frac{3 w_a z}{z+1}\Big] \Big(2(z+1)^2((1-\Omega_m)(z+1)^{3(w_a+w_0)}+  \Omega_m e^{\frac{3 z w_a}{z+1}})\Big)^{-1}
\end{multline}
```

which gives me

[image]

as you can see q(z) is slightly moved to the left and the 2 equations do not appear aligned.
Is there a better way to display long equations on latex?

Comment: Please always provide full (but minimal) examples instead of sniplets where we have to add code to even test the code.

Comment: multline would not align `q` with `j` under most circumstances.  It tries to move the first line as far left as possible, the last as far right, and those in between are centered.  That doesn't appear to have happened here because the equations are too long.  If you want alignment from amsmath, you'd want the align environment.  But you'd still have problems because of the long equations.

Comment: @daleif ah sorry i forgot. next time i will do better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `flalign` from `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
q(z) & = \frac{(1-\Omega_m)(3zw_a + 3w_0(z+1)+z+1)(z+1)^{3(w_a + w_0)}
            +(z+1)\Omega_m \mathrm{e}^{\tfrac{3z w_a}{z+1}}}
            {2(z+1)[(1-\Omega_m)(z+1)^{3(w_a +w_0)}
            +\Omega_m \mathrm{e}^{\tfrac{3 z w_a}{z+1}}]}       
            \notag      \\
j(z) & = \bigg[(1-\Omega_m)(9 z^2 w_a^2 + 3(z+1)w_a(6 w_0 z + 3z +1) 
            + (9w_0(w_0+1)+2)(z+1)^2)(z+1)^{3(w_a+w_0)}             
            \notag      \\
     & \qquad   
        +2(z+1)^2 \Omega_m \frac{3 w_a z}{z+1}\biggr] \biggl(2(z+1)^2\Bigl((1-\Omega_m)(z+1)^{3(w_a+w_0)}
        +  \Omega_m \mathrm{e}^{\tfrac{3 z w_a}{z+1}}\Bigr)\biggr)^{-1}
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(grey lines indicate text area borders)

**Addendum:**
One possibilities is to split equation `j(z)` into three lines and introduce new variable `z' = z - 1`. Consider default `article` page layout:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
q(z) & = \frac{(1-\Omega_m)\bigl(3zw_a + 3w_0(z')+z'\bigr)(z')^{3(w_a + w_0)}
            +(z+1)\Omega_m \mathrm{e}^{\tfrac{3z w_a}{z'}}}
            {2(z')[(1-\Omega_m)(z')^{3(w_a +w_0)}
            +\Omega_m \mathrm{e}^{\tfrac{3 z w_a}{z'}}]}       
            \notag      \\
j(z) & = \bigg[(1-\Omega_m)\bigl(9 z^2 w_a^2 + 3(z')w_a(6 w_0 z + 3z +1)
            \notag      \\ 
     & \qquad
        + (9w_0(w_0+1)+2)(z')^2\bigr)(z)^{3(w_a+w_0)}             
        + 2(z')^2 \Omega_m \frac{3 w_a z}{z'}\biggr]\cdot
            \notag      \\
     & \qquad
        \biggl(2(z')^2\Bigl((1-\Omega_m)(z')^{3(w_a+w_0)}
        + \Omega_m \mathrm{e}^{\tfrac{3 z w_a}{z'}}\Bigr)\biggr)^{-1}
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines show part of article page layout)

Comment: the second option works well.  thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are many solutions possible. One can be to use the `IEEEeqnarray*` (`*` for suppressing equation no) environment from the `IEEEtrantools` package. Its usage has similarities with the `tabular` environment. You can specify the no of columns for alignment and `r`, `C`, and `l` are for right, centered (with little more space), and left alignment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry} %Used for increased textwidth.
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{*rCl} %the * type glue ensures that the whole equation is left aligned not centered
        q(z) &=& \frac{(1-\Omega_m)(3zw_a + 3w_0(z+1)+z+1)(z+1)^{3(w_a + w_0)}+(z+1)\Omega_m e^{\frac{3z w_a}{z+1}}}{2(z+1)[(1-\Omega_m)(z+1)^{3(w_a +w_0)}+\Omega_m e^{\frac{3 z w_a}{z+1}}]} \\
        j(z) &=& \Big[(1-\Omega_m)(9 z^2 w_a^2 + 3(z+1)w_a(6 w_0 z + 3z +1) + (9w_0(w_0+1)+2) (z+1)^2)\times\\
             & & (z+1)^{3(w_a+w_0)}+2(z+1)^2 \Omega_m \frac{3 w_a z}{z+1}\Big] \Big(2(z+1)^2((1-\Omega_m)(z+1)^{3(w_a+w_0)}+  \Omega_m e^{\frac{3 z w_a}{z+1}})\Big)^{-1} \IEEEeqnarraynumspace\IEEEyesnumber
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

The `IEEEyesnumber` inserts equation no and the `IEEEeqnarraynumspace` makes sure that there is no overlapping between the equation no and the equation.

Answer (score 2):

I propose to load the `geometry` package to have more decent margins, and to use an `aligned` environment for the second equation, nested in a global `align`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
        q(z) & = \frac{(1-\Omega_m)(3zw_a + 3w_0(z+1)+z+1)(z+1)^{3(w_a + w_0)}+(z+1)\Omega_m e^{\frac{3z w_a}{z+1}}}{2(z+1)[(1-\Omega_m)(z+1)^{3(w_a +w_0)}+\Omega_m e^{\frac{3 z w_a}{z+1}}]} \\
        j(z) & = \biggl[\begin{aligned}[t] (1-\Omega_m)(9 z^2 w_a^2 + 3(z+1)w_a(6 w_0 z + 3z +1) + (9w_0(w_0+1)+2) (z+1)^2)\times{}\\
          (z+1)^{3(w_a+w_0)}+2(z+1)^2 \Omega_m \frac{3 w_a z}{z+1}\biggr]\bm\cdot {}\\
        \Bigl(2(z+1)^2((1-\Omega_m)(z+1)^{3(w_a+w_0)}+ \Omega_m e^{\frac{3 z w_a}{z+1}})\Bigr)^{\!\!\mathrlap{-1}}
        \end{aligned}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]